# Keepalive.aspx - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: configuration

CM and CD hosted in azure web apps.

We are seeing a quiet lot of exception below on both CD and CMS environments.

Note that we have a patch file which patches and we have custom rewrite rule from http to https.

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:00">
        <param desc="url">https://mysite.azurewebsite.net/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx</param>
        <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
      </agent>
```

ERROR:

```
ManagedPoolThread #9 04:16:02 INFO  Scheduling.UrlAgent started. Url: https://mysite.azurewebsite.net/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx
ManagedPoolThread #9 04:16:02 ERROR Exception in UrlAgent (url: https://mysite.azurewebsite.net/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx)
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Source: System
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
   at Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ExecuteWebPage(String url, NameValueCollection headers)
   at Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent.Run()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.IO.IOException
Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

Has anyone faced this issue and have possible solution?

Comment: Can you browse to https://mysite.azurewebsite.net on the server itself?

Comment: Yep I can access on browser

Comment: Can you disable the SSL redirect and try it over non SSL?  How old is your certificate?  Maybe the certificate only supports older encryption methods.

Comment: Works fine without https. In regards to cert. its one comes with azure web apps out of box

Comment: SSL termination on the web server or at a load balancer or application gateway?  Is the request for the URL routing over the public internet or is there a loopback entry in your host file?  If so you could be requesting SSL and the server is expecting non SSL at that point.

Comment: Its hosted on azure web apps

Comment: I don't have any experience with the hosted azure app, but since it works over non SSL it does feel like the redirect into SSL is the issue.  Maybe put in an exception for the keep alive path?

Comment: This is going to be a poor comment because I don't know how to get around it.. but this seems like a TLS issue.